# How to parse request content to strong type in function?

Tags: c#, json, httprequest

I can parse request content to strong type like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage API_Notify(NotifyModel notify)
{
    .
    .
    .
    .
}
```

but how to parse it inside a function? like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage API_Notify()
{
    .
    .
    NotifyModel notify = ToModelMethod<NotifyModel>(Request.Content)
    .
    .
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var contentJson = await Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
NotifyModel notify = JsonConvert.Deserialize<NotifyModel >(contentJson );
```

Comment: I try your way, but my `contentJson` would be `orderNo=D2311&amount=100` not `{ "orderNo":"D2311", "amount":100}`, that caused `Deserialize` error

Comment: It's success now, I try `HttpUtility.ParseQueryString` then `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` and finally your way, thanks.